# What does this symbol means?

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics, notation

I saw this expression in an article, and i don't know what does the horizontal 【I】 means.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvOIj.png)

Answer (score 2):

$\Xi$ is just a Greek letter called [Xi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xi_(letter)); it's the capital version of $\xi$.

Presumably in this context it's just being used as a variable.